# XUbuntu desktop clock is slow by 3 hours, even though timedatectl shows correct info?

Tags: xubuntu, clock

The system clock on my desktop is 3 hours behind, despite my setting the proper timezone in settings. The output from `timedatectl` seems to confirm this.

[image]

Also, here is how my desktop clock is formatted:

```
%a %b %e - %I:%M %p
```

What's going on here?

Comment: my clock is configured with `%a, %d %b  %H:%M` and format is set to "Custom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop to terminal, and run

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

The choose the appropriate location for your time zone.

If that has no effect, then boot into bios, and review the system time.

Comment: BIOS time was somehow off, even though I remember resetting it when I installed XUbuntu maybe 3 days ago.

Thanks.

Comment: @BearCub Might have been a choice made during the install, regarding the time, asking if the host uses universal time.